# How to get arguments from the command line(assembly nasm ubuntu 32bit)?

Tags: assembly, command, arguments, nasm

I want to 'print' the argument in command line,
for example, 
When i type "$./sum3 10" (at command line),
number '10' must be shown next line

(like this)

$./sum3 10
10

and this is the code.

```
            segment .bss
     p_arv  resd 1
            segment .text
            global main
     main:
            enter 0,0
            pusha

            mov eax, dword [ebp+12] ; move pointer to argv to eax
            mov [p_argv], eax

            mov eax, [p_argv + 4] ; move number '10' to eax
            call print_int
            call print_nl

            popa
            mov eax, 0
            leave 
            ret
```

I expected the stack will be

--------------------------stack top
10                 (argv[1],   [p_argv+4])
./sum3              (argv[0],   [p_argv])

...

pointer to argv        (EBP+12)
number of arguments    (EBP+8)
return address of main
EBP

----------------------- stack bottom

But,

the result is

$./sum3 10
0

I cannot understand why '0' is shown.
so how can i get the right number(argument)?

Comment: The shell passes the name of the program (`./sum3`) as `argv[0]`.  You want `argv[1]`.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your post. Your code has `mov eax, dword [ebp+8] ; move pointer to argv to eax` (the comment says you are accessing `ebp+8` to get to the `argv` pointer). But your later comment says, *pointer to argv (EBP+12)*. Are you sure you know where the pointer to `argv` is? You also have `mov eax, [p_argv + 4] ; move number '10' to eax`. The comment isn't correct. You aren't moving the number 10 to `eax`. You're actually moving a pointer to an ASCII string representation of 10 (assuming you have the `argv` pointer correct, that is). So `print_int` may not be the right call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example looks like an "assembly-coded" C-function, e.g. a C compiler adds some startcode and calls it like a function. In this startcode the Linux commandline is processed to C parameters which looks like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) resp. int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

You get only **two** arguments on the stack: a number (argc) and a pointer to a list of pointers to a string. You have to dereference these pointers.

Take a look at this example:

```
; Name:     get_argv_gcc.asm
; Assemble: nasm -felf32 get_argv_gcc.asm
; Link:     gcc -m32 -oget_argv_gcc get_argv_gcc.o
; Run:      ./get_argv_gcc arg1 arg2 arg3

SECTION  .data
    argcstr     db `argc = %d\n\0`      ; backquotes for C-escapes
    argvstr     db `argv[%u] = %s\n\0`

SECTION .text
global  main
extern printf
main:

    push ebp                    ; Prolog
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx                    ; Callee saved registers
    push esi

    mov eax, [ebp + 8]          ; argc
    push eax
    push argcstr
    call printf                 ; Call libc
    add esp, (2*4)              ; Adjust stack by 2 arguments

    mov esi, [ebp + 12]         ; **argv
    mov ebx, 0                  ; Index of argv
    .J1:
    mov eax, [esi + ebx * 4]    ; *argv[ebx]
    test eax, eax               ; Null pointer?
    je .J2                      ; Yes -> end of loop
    push eax                    ; Pointer to string
    push ebx                    ; Integer
    push argvstr                ; Pointer to format string
    call printf                 ; Call libc
    add esp, (3*4)              ; Adjust stack by 3 arguments
    inc ebx
    jmp .J1                     ; Loop
    .J2:

    xor eax, eax                ; Returncode = return(0)
    pop esi                     ; Epilog
    pop ebx
    leave
    ret
```

A pure assembly program which is called by the shell gets the arguments slightly different on the stack. There's an excellent article about it:  [NASM - Linux Getting command line parameters](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285550-nasm-linux-getting-command-line-parameters/). Try my example:

```
; Name:     get_argv.asm
; Assemble: nasm -felf32 get_argv.asm
; Link:     ld -m elf_i386 -o get_argv get_argv.o
; Run:      ./get_argv arg1 arg2 arg3

SECTION  .data
    LineFeed    dw  10
    nullstr     db '(null)',0
    argcstr     db 'argc = '
    argcstr1    db '---------------',0
    argvstr     db 'argv['
    argvstr1    db '---------------',0
    argvstr2    db '] = ',0

SECTION .text
global  _start
_start:

    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp + 4]          ; argc
    mov edi, argcstr1
    call EAX_to_DEC             ; Convert EAX to a string pointed by EDI

    mov esi, argcstr
    call PrintString
    mov esi, LineFeed
    call PrintString

    xor ecx, ecx

    .J1:
    mov eax, ecx
    mov edi, argvstr1
    call EAX_to_DEC             ; Convert EAX to a string pointed by EDI

    mov esi, argvstr
    call PrintString
    mov esi, argvstr2
    call PrintString
    mov esi, [ebp+8+4*ecx]      ; argv[ECX]
    call PrintString
    test esi, esi
    jz .J2
    mov esi, LineFeed
    call PrintString
    add ecx, 1
    jmp .J1
    .J2:

    .exit:
    mov esi, LineFeed
    call PrintString

    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp

    mov     eax, 1              ; SYS_EXIT
    xor     ebx, ebx            ; Exit code = 0 = no error
    int     0x80                ; Call Linux

PrintString:                    ; ARG: ESI Pointer to ASCIZ string
    pusha
    test esi, esi
    jne .J0
    mov esi, nullstr
    .J0:
    mov eax, 4                  ; SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, 1                  ; STDOUT
    mov ecx, esi
    xor edx, edx                ; Count of bytes to send
    .J1:
    cmp byte [esi], 0           ; Look for the terminating null
    je .J2
    add edx, 1
    add esi, 1
    jmp .J1
    .J2:
    int 0x80                    ; Call Linux
    popa
    ret

EAX_to_DEC:                     ; ARG: EAX integer, EDI pointer to string buffer
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx

    mov ebx, 10                 ; Divisor = 10
    xor ecx, ecx                ; ECX=0 (digit counter)
    .J1:                        ; First Loop: store the remainders
    xor edx, edx                ; Don't forget it!
    div ebx                     ; EDX:EAX / EBX = EAX remainder EDX
    push dx                     ; Push the digit in DL (LIFO)
    add cl, 1                   ; = inc cl (digit counter)
    or eax, eax                 ; AX == 0?
    jnz .J1                     ; No: once more
    mov ebx, ecx                ; Store count of digits
    .J2:                        ; Second loop: load the remainders in reversed order
    pop ax                      ; get back pushed digits
    or al, 00110000b            ; to ASCII
    mov [edi], al               ; Store AL to [EDI] (EDI is a pointer to a buffer)
    add edi, 1                  ; = inc edi
    loop .J2                    ; until there are no digits left
    mov byte [edi], 0           ; ASCIIZ terminator (0)
    mov eax, ebx                ; Restore Count of digits

    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    ret                         ; RET: EAX length of string (w/o last null)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! most helpful